# Convert Tweepy Status object into JSON

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm using [Tweepy](http://www.tweepy.org) to download tweets. I have a program that then writes the actual `Status` object to a file in text form. How do I translate this into JSON, or import this object back into Python? I've tried using the JSON library to encode, but Status is not JSON serializable.

Comment: I did, I've tried using the JSON Library, but the object isn't JSON serializable

Answer (score 105, accepted):

The `Status` object of tweepy itself is not JSON serializable, but it has a `_json` property which contains JSON serializable response data. For example:

```
>>> status_list = api.user_timeline(user_handler)
>>> status = status_list[0]
>>> json_str = json.dumps(status._json)
```

Comment: Note that this is a private attribute set on the [model](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/cd46550b3ef068857f5de9c37bbdd0a72acb7462/tweepy/models.py#L78) and not mentioned anywhere in the docs, nor used elsewhere in the code. So it may conceivably be removed one day.

But on the other hand, as long as it's there, you can just as easily use it to create json dumps of the whole list using `json.dumps([status._json for status in status_list])`.

Comment: @yoniLavi yes, it wasn't mentioned in the doc and it was hard to find. On the other hand this is very useful. One of my teammates figured it out while we were trying to dump raw data on files. Hopefully tweepy developers will add this or something equivalent as documented method in future.

Answer (score 12):

A better way to do this is to use a tweepy parser. It's not documented very well - see the [Tweepy API reference](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/8ad187e235c218ae6249cdc121e9c0d51ccd191f/docs/api.rst#modtweepyapi-----twitter-api-wrapper) - but it's a public API, so much safer than using the `_json` property.

```
import tweepy
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth, parser=tweepy.parsers.JSONParser())
status = api.user_timeline(user=username, count=1)[0]
json.dumps(status)
```

`status` is now a json object.

Comment: this is not (anymore?) true

Comment: I tried: status = `api.get_status(tweet_id)` and it gives me: `(<all_tweets_fields>) is not JSON serializable`

Try it yourself, if you can

Comment: but it should be a Status Object, so I think Status Object are not JSON serializable.

Comment: it gives me the same error for the example you posted, so even for user_timeline

Comment: Works in Python 3.7 and it should be the preferred solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
users = api.search_users('TimHortons', 1)
print(json.dumps(users[0]._json))
```

Use `json.dumps(users[0]._json)` if object has _json. Users was only an example.

Answer (score 0):

With the latest versions of tweepy, this became much easier. You only need to pass `return_type=dict` when you construct your client:

```
client_v2 = tweepy.Client(
    bearer_token="",
    consumer_key="",        # api key in dev page
    consumer_secret="",     # api key secret in dev page
    access_token="",        # for user
    access_token_secret="", # for user 
    return_type=dict,       # <<----- not mentioned in examples
)
response = client_v2.SOME_METHOD(...)
print(json.dumps(response, indent=4))
```