# Query Twitter Status by Using Python and Tweepy

Tags: python, json, twitter, tweepy

I try to query a specified user's tweets with a specified key word included in the tweet text. Here is my code:

```
# Import Tweepy, sleep, credentials.py
import tweepy
from time import sleep
from credentials import *

# Access and authorize our Twitter credentials from credentials.py
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

SCREEN_NAME = "BachelorABC"
KEYWORD = "TheBachelor"

def twtr2():
    raw_tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=KEYWORD, lang="en").items(50)
    for tweet in raw_tweets:
        if tweet['user']['screen_name'] == SCREEN_NAME:
            print tweet
twtr2()
```

I get the error message as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 19, in <module>
    twtr2()
  File "test2.py", line 17, in twtr2
    if tweet['user']['screen_name'] == SCREEN_NAME:
TypeError: 'Status' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I googled a lot and thought that maybe I needed to save Twitter's JSON in python first, so I tried the following:

```
import tweepy, json
from time import sleep
from credentials import *

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

SCREEN_NAME = "BachelorABC"
KEYWORD = "TheBachelor"

raw_tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=KEYWORD, lang="en").items(50)
for tweet in raw_tweets:
    load_tweet = json.loads(tweet)
    if load_tweet['user']['screen_name'] == SCREEN_NAME:
        print tweet
```

However, the result is sad:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 35, in <module>
    load_tweet = json.loads(tweet)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with my code? And can you help me to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out. Here is the solution:

```
# Import Tweepy, sleep, credentials.py
import tweepy
from time import sleep
from credentials import *

# Access and authorize our Twitter credentials from credentials.py
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

SCREEN_NAME = "BachelorABC"
KEYWORD = "TheBachelor"
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=KEYWORD, lang="en").items(200):
    if tweet.user.screen_name == SCREEN_NAME:
        print tweet.text
        print tweet.user.screen_name
```

Please do note that this is not an efficient way to locate the tweets with both specified conditions (screen_name and keyword) satisfied. This is because we query by keyword first, and then query by screen_name. If the keyword is very popular, like what I use here "TheBachelor", with a limited number of tweets (200), we may find none of the 200 tweets are sent by the specified screen_name. I think if we can query by screen_name first, and then by keyword, maybe it will provide a better result. But that's out of the discussion.

I will leave you here.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the

```
load_tweet = json.loads(tweet)
```

The "tweet" object is not a JSON object. If you want to use JSON objects, follow this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27900451/convert-tweepy-status-object-into-json) post on how to use JSON objects with tweepy.

To achieve what you are trying to do (print each tweet of a feed of 50), I would follow what was stated in the [getting started docs](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/docs/getting_started.rst):

```
import tweepy

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

public_tweets = api.home_timeline()
for tweet in public_tweets:
    print(tweet.text)
```

Comment: Thanks for your time @ethanchewy I am looking for tweets with **specified** screen_name and keyword. Your answer is about the first 20 tweets in general. Do you have any idea to locate the tweets with these conditions?

Comment: @LinguisticsStudent Take a look at the last code snippet located over here: https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/docs/code_snippet.rst . You would store the screen_names in a list and then search within that list for a certain screen_name.

Note that Twitter has strict limitations for querying.

Comment: Thanks @ethanchewy. The page you quote above is to retrieve the screen_name from follower or user, not status. I will update if I find an answer later.

Comment: FYI, @ethanchewy I posted my answer above.