# How to convert a Status Object to type String?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tweepy

I'm working with Tweepy, so I'm running into a problem where I need to change a status object to type String.

I looked over the Tweepy Documentation and couldn't find any information on how to. I've tried a couple of things but had no luck.

```
for s in tweet:
    sn = s.user.screen_name
    m = "@%s Nice Post" % (sn)
    s = api.update_status(m, s.id)
```

Comment: Did you try `str()` on the status object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting integer to string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961632/converting-integer-to-string-in-python)

Comment: @cdarke it was the first thing I tried, had no luck with it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Tweepy Status object into JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27900451/convert-tweepy-status-object-into-json)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Tweepy Status object into JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27900451/convert-tweepy-status-object-into-json)

Answer (score 1):

Let's say "tweet" is a "tweepy.models.Status" object, you can convert it to a string like so:

```
import json
json.dumps(tweet._json)
```