# How do I json serialize tweet data I get from the tweepy api?

Tags: python, json, tweepy

I'm trying to get the text from tweets about a hashtag that can be input and then store them in a json file so that I can do stuff like count how many times a word is used in all the tweets.

I tried to cast tweet as a string with str(tweet) but that just gave a different error and I mostly just did it as a guess.

```
api = tweepy.API(auth)

def jsontweetdump(tweet):
  with open('tweet.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(tweet, outfile)

hashtag = input()

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, hashtag, count=10).items():
  jsontweetdump(tweet)
```

I expected that this would store data from ten tweets based on the hashtag i put in in a json file but I'm getting these error messages.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 22, in <module>
    jsontweetdump(tweet)
  File "main.py", line 17, in jsontweetdump
    json.dump(tweet, outfile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 179, in dump
    for chunk in iterable:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line437, in _iterencode
    o = _default(o)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line180, in default
    o.__class__.__name__)
TypeError: Object of type 'Status' is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27901076) looks like it might be what you need.

Comment: Yep this fixed it completely, thanks!